# ffmpeg auto ended process with output error

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ffmpeg, streaming

How do you make ffmpeg stop during processing if strange words appear which make the live stream error automatically stop?

For example, during the process I often get output like this:

```
Non-Monotonous DTS in 0:1 output stream
```

It keeps repeating. My streaming results are never normal. If the source of the error indication is like anything then I want the ffmpeg process to stop.

Comment: You can try the `-err_detect` option with various flags: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html

Comment: What is your ffmpeg command?